# Python: take max N elements from some list

Tags: python, max

Is there some function which would return me the N highest elements from some list?

I.e. if `max(l)` returns the single highest element, sth. like `max(l, count=10)` would return me a list of the 10 highest numbers (or less if `l` is smaller).

Or what would be an efficient easy way to get these? (Except the obvious canonical implementation; also, no such things which involve sorting the whole list first because that would be inefficient compared to the canonical solution.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1034846/64633

Comment: heapq.nlargest is the way to go for really big lists, but on my system, sorted(l)[:count] is faster up until the list reaches ~25000 elements.

Comment: sorted(l,reverse=True)[0:N]

Answer (score 60, accepted):

[`heapq.nlargest`](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest):

```
>>> import heapq, random
>>> heapq.nlargest(3, (random.gauss(0, 1) for _ in xrange(100)))
[1.9730767232998481, 1.9326532289091407, 1.7762926716966254]
```

Comment: Does it return the values in the order they were stored?

Comment: @LoukasPap See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest).

Answer (score 7):

The function in the standard library that does this is [`heapq.nlargest`](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest)

Answer (score 3):

Start with the first 10 from L, call that X. Note the minimum value of X.

Loop over L[i] for i over the rest of L.

If L[i] is greater than min(X), drop min(X) from X and insert L[i]. You may need to keep X as a sorted linked list and do an insertion. Update min(X).

At the end, you have the 10 largest values in X.

I suspect that will be O(kN) (where k is 10 here) since insertion sort is linear. Might be what gsl uses, so if you can read some C code:

http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Selecting-the-k-smallest-or-largest-elements.html

Probably something in numpy that does this.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant with the obvious canonical solution. :) (Basically a generalized `min` algorithm.)

Answer (score 1):

A fairly efficient solution is a variation of quicksort where recursion is limited to the right part of the pivot until the pivot point position is higher than the number of elements required (with a few extra conditions to deal with border cases of course).

The standard library has `heapq.nlargest`, as pointed out by others here.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind using pandas then:

```
import pandas as pd
N = 10
column_name = 0
pd.DataFrame(your_array).nlargest(N, column_name)
```

The above code will show you the N largest values along with the index position of each value.

[Pandas nlargest documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html)