# Use List Comprehension to get the top n items

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I tried:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,100,-1]
y = [a for a in x.sort()[0:5]]
print(y)
y = y[0:4]
print(y)
```

but that won't work because sort() doesn't return the sorted list

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-d13e11c1e8ab> in <module>
      1 x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,100,-1]
----> 2 y = [a for a in x.sort()[0:5]]
      3 print(y)
      4 y = y[0:4]
      5 print(y)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215472/python-take-max-n-elements-from-some-list

Comment: Why do you want to use list comprehension for this? Does not seem like an appropriate use. Why not simple sort and then first 5 items?

Comment: `y = sorted(x, reverse=True)[:5]`

Comment: 'Cause I'm doing other things in the LC expression and LC is super cool and I want to be a Pythonista. ;)

Comment: part of being a good Python programmer is knowing when to use certain things and when not to. simply indexing a list is not a good use of LC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.sort()` sorts the list in-place

> list.sort() sorts the list in-place, mutating the list indices, and
> returns None (like all in-place operations)

so you'd have to do this:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,100,-1]
x.sort()
y = [a for a in x[0:5]]
print(y)
y = y[0:4]
print(y)
```

Output:

```
[-1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[-1, 1, 2, 3]
```

[The difference between .sort() and sorted() in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442378/what-is-the-difference-between-sortedlist-vs-list-sort).